# Persisting a mongodb connection across all node.js router modules

Tags: node.js, mongodb, persist

Given the following app.js code:

```html
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var mongodb = require('mongodb');

var db = null;

mongodb.MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost/mysite', function(err, database) {
  if(err) throw err;
 
  db = database;

  app.listen(3000);
  console.log('Listening on port 3000');
});

var outside = require('./outside');
app.use('/outside', outside);

app.get('/inside', function(req, res) {
    collection = db.collection('pages');
    collection.find({}, function(err, data) {
        if(data) {
            res.send('inside worked');
        }else {
            console.log('oops');
        }
    });
});
```

and the outside.js code as follows:

```html
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    collection = db.collection('pages');
    collection.find({}, function(err, data) {
        if(data) {
            res.send('outside worked');
        }else {
            console.log('oops');
        }
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

if I use "var db = null" as shown, it is local to the app and when the inside route runs it is available to it, but it is not available to the outside route.

If I use "db = null" making it a global, it is available to both routes.  I am not sure if that is the correct/most elegant way to do it.  If it is, let me know, otherwise let me know a better way, taking account I don't want to create a new connection each time and I want to take advantage of pools, as noted in other similar posts here.

Per the comment on the other similar post, I changed the line in app.js:

db = database;
to
  db = database;
  app.locals.db = database;

and added the line to outside.js:

```
var db = req.app.locals.db;
```

so it now reads:
    var db = req.app.locals.db;
    collection = db.collection('pages');

This does work, but as mentioned in the other post, I'm not sure if this reuses the connection or opens a new one or if it uses connection pools properly.

Answer (score 1):

What I did in a project was the following:

-Separate the connection in a separate js file called "init-mongoose.js"

```
const connection = mongoose.connect("mongoURL")
module.exports = connection
```

-Require the connection whenever I want to use it

```
const connection = include('libs/init-mongoose.js')
```

One of advantages of this model is that if you need to close the connection in one part of the code, all parts of code sharing this connection will have it closed. In my case I was running several nodejs batch-scripts with a single call and needed to close the connection in the last script

Hope my answer was helpful

Comment: Thanks.  Does that use the existing connection and connection pool across the application or does it open a new connect each time it is used?

Comment: It used the connection throughout the application. If my answer was useful, please accept/upvote ;)

Comment: Thanks Israel.  I upvoted your answer.  I'm new to this so is it ok to wait for some comments from others who are more knowledgable than me saying this is the best answer before I accept this?

Comment: Yes, wait for the other answers before you accept some. But you should accept the one someday.

Answer (score 0):

you can also do it without requiring connection in every file.Store the connection variable in the global

```
global.connection = mongodb.MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost/mysite',function(err,database) {
     if(err) throw err;

     db = database;

     app.listen(3000);
     console.log('Listening on port 3000');
});
```

and then you can use it

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
     global['collection'] = db.collection('pages');
     global['collection'].find({}, function(err, data) {
         if(data) {
             res.send('outside worked');
         }else {
             console.log('oops');
         }
     });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Ashish.  This is similar to what what I mentioned in my post about using a global variable vs. local.  Are there any downsides to using a global variable?

Comment: yes there can be some downsides. In this solution this connection variable will always be live and will occupy space in your memory unitl you restart your app.So storing small values or data will not affect much, but storing a large set of data will reduce your machine's memory space.